# Background position offset from bottom: opposite behaviour in Chrome and Firefox

Tags: css, google-chrome, firefox, background-position

I found an opposite result in Firefox and Chrome when rendering a gradient background with offset set.

Here my css code:

```
html
{
   background:linear-gradient(to bottom, rgba(245,245,245,1) 0%,rgba(255,255,255,0) 8%);
   background-position: center top 30px;
}

body
{
   background:linear-gradient(to bottom, rgba(255,255,255,0) 92%,rgba(245,245,245,1) 100%);
   background-position: center bottom 100px;
}
```

The idea is to apply a sort of "Sliding doors" of background applying 2 opposite gradient onto html and body elements.

**The problem rises when I set the bottom offset in Body tag**: Firefox translates up with positive values, while Chrome translate up with negative values (or bottom with positive). So two major browsers  have opposite behaviour.

How to solve this?

Comment: I don't think it's a good idea to style `html` and `body`. I'd use two `div`s and apply the gradient on them.

Comment: It's a not so rare solution.... documented on many websites... ;-)

Comment: Can you point to a testcase showing your problem?  I tried this locally, and for both browsers positive values for offset from bottom mean translation up (which is what the spec requires).

Comment: Look at this: [link](http://jsfiddle.net/pfbJJ/1)
Particularly attention to Background. Firefox shows the correct behaviour. To obatin the same in Chrome, I must to set a negative value for bottom offset!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found solution for Chrome!

It is sufficient to add

```
 background-repeat:no-repeat;
```

to BODY tag css declaration, as showed in this [updated JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/pfbJJ/3/):